# Dominated Convergence Theorem Change of Assumptions

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

The Dominated Convergence Theorem states that we can have $\lim_n\int|f_n-f|d\mu=0$ provided that $|f_n-f|\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and $|f_n|\le g$, where $0\le g\in L^1(d\mu)$.

Can we take it a step further and say that this theorem holds if instead of $|f_n|\le g$, we have that:
$$\int|f_n-f|d\mu\le\int|g|d\mu$$
while we still have $|f_n-f|\rightarrow0$?

Comment: You can weaken it to convergence in distribution via skorokhod representation  if you are doing probability

Comment: It’s worth noting your suggested hypothesis is point wise convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't. Take $f = 0$, and $f_n = n^{-1}\chi_{[0,n]}$. Then $\int f_n = 1$ for every $n$, $f_n\to 0$, and $\int f_n \le \int g$ for any $g\ge0$ with integral $1$. The reason this assumption won't work is that the requirement that $\int |f_n-f|\le \int |g|$ doesn't say anything about how the mass of $|f_n-f|$ is distributed, whereas $|f_n|\le g$ is a much stronger assumption that controls the distribution of $|f_n|$.